# Substitution function in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, substitution, quantifiers

After reading some articles on [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)), I've been trying to translate the substitution operation to first-order logic. For example, given a term $P(x, y)$ and the substitution function $\sigma = \{x \rightarrow a, y \rightarrow b\}$, then $P(x, y) \sigma = P(a, b)$. My first hypothesis is that the expression $P(x, y) \sigma$ means $\exists x \exists y[P(x, y) \land x=a \land y =b]$, which is logically equivalent to $P(a, b)$. A second hypothesis would be that $P(x, y) \sigma$ stands for $\forall x \forall y[x=a \land y=b \rightarrow P(x, y)]$, which is also equivalent to $P(a, b)$. However, in both cases, the function $\sigma$ is presented as the identity function $\sigma(x)=x$, which is not a requirement for $\sigma$ according to the formal definition of the substitution function. Does anyone have any idea for possible translations in FOL of such logical expression $P(x, y)\sigma$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  You already know what $P(x,y)\sigma$ stands for, namely $P(a,b)$.

Comment: Mr Wofsey, thank you for the reply. I'm trying to better understand how $P(a, b)$ derives from $P(x, y)$ in a functional relation. I'd like to visualize in a logical expression how the substution function applied over any term P is equivalent to the correspondent substitution instance.

Comment: It is defined in every textbook; see e.g. [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf), page 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution operation $\sigma$ is not part of the formal language
of first order logic. It is part of the metalanguage. If "$f$"
is a function symbol of the language and "$x$" a symbol of a
variable or of a constant, thus, a term of the formal language, then
"$f(x)$" is also a term of the formal language. But either the
symbol "$\sigma$" or the expression "$P(x,y)\sigma$" belong
to the language. Moreover, $f$ maps the possible values of $x$ with
the correspondent values of $f(x)$. The substitution operation $\sigma$,
on the other hand, is a map from a set of symbols to another set of
symbols: from the variables to the terms. It would be more accurate
to write: $\sigma=\{"x" \mapsto"a","y"\mapsto"b"\}$. It is not possible
to express $\sigma$ in the formal language, because the symbols of
the language are not elements of the set of objects from witch the
terms of the language take their values. Only outside of the language
you can have that kind of a map, where you can treat the symbols of
the language as objects (individuals).